How to format a number to Euros currency format in dataweave?
I have a number, let's say - 287901.45
I want to format it to the string - "287.901,45 EUR"
How to do this dynamically?
I'm currently doing the below
%dw 2.0
output application/json
 
fun formatEU(number) =
    number as String {format: "#,##0.00"} 
        replace "." with "[temp]" 
        replace "," with "." 
        replace "[temp]" with ","
 
var number = 287901.45
---
formatEU(number) as String ++ " EUR" 

Is there a better way to do this?

You can use a locale in the conversion to String so the format is automatically configured. For example the Spanish locale (es) has the right format for your output.
Example:
%dw 2.0
output application/json
 
fun formatEU(number) =
    number as String {format: "#,##0.00", locale:"es"} 
 
var number = 287901.45
---
formatEU(number) as String ++ " EUR" 

Output:
"287.901,45 EUR"


%dw 2.0
output application/json
 
fun formatEU(number) = 
    number as String {format: '#,##0.00', locale: "EU"}
 

var number = 287901.44
---
formatEU(number) as String ++ " EUR"

